# setMultiChoiceItems With Icon in Dialog - Android

Tags: android, dialog, icons, adapter, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to set an adapter with icons to AlertDialog method, setMultiChoiceItems, but the only method that its accept is for setSingleChoiceItems, but it must to be multichoice. User click in a button and shows a dialog with the icons that he can select. I already searched in documentation about alert.dialog, adapter, and I did found nothing related. The question is, how to create an adapter or something that have string and image icon to set in dialog.

My code:

```
final String [] items = new String[] {"Music", "Sport"};
    final Integer[] icons = new Integer[] {R.drawable.iconmusictest, R.drawable.iconsporttest};
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithIcon(Register30.this, items, icons);



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register30.this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
        }
    })
    .setTitle("Select your likes")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    final AlertDialog popUpLikes = builder.create();
```

My class that returns a custom adapter:

```
public class ArrayAdapterWithIcon extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private List<Integer> images;

public ArrayAdapterWithIcon(Context context, String[] items, Integer[] images) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    this.images = Arrays.asList(images);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(images.get(position), 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(images.get(position), 0, 0, 0);
    }
    textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    return view;
}
```

}

What I'm trying to do:
[image: dialog]

Comment: You should try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I be more specific? I have a dialog, that must be like the image, but I cant pass an adapter with icons to method setMultiChoiceItems in dialog.

Comment: Hi bro, I hope you will found a solution. I could use your solution for my `setSingleChoiceItems` and it works properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
  boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[items.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (selectedItems.contains(i)) {
    checkedItems[i] = true;
   } else {
    checkedItems[i] = false;
   }
}

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkedItems, new 
  DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, 
  boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                selectedItems.add(indexSelected);
            }
            else if (selectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // TODO
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            filterDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: No need of adapter, you can use array only

Comment: where are the icons?